# InvalidArgument error when trying to complete one multipart upload in Google Cloud Storage

Tags: google-cloud-storage

When sending the POST request to complete the multipart upload, I am seeing the `InvalidArgument` error with status code `400`.

To be more clear, I have tried the following things:

1. Upload one single part and then complete the multipart upload, it works well and I can see the object created in GCS
2. Upload two parts, then in the complete multipart upload request, chose one of them only and it can work without any issues.
3. Upload two parts, then specify all of them in the requests, it failed.
4. Upload two parts, then specify all of them in the requests, randomly change some values in the request body and I will get some other errors which surely make sense.

The document I followed to send the request is: https://cloud.google.com/storage/docs/xml-api/post-object-complete

The request body that failed (with both two parts in the body):

```
<CompleteMultipartUpload>
   <Part>
      <PartNumber>1</PartNumber>
      <ETag>892e38f38955a0dc8d70f3db79e0a86b</ETag>
   </Part>
   <Part>
      <PartNumber>2</PartNumber>
      <ETag>490779791c8f2bf28508e22d75057524</ETag>
   </Part>
</CompleteMultipartUpload>
```

The full error message is just `Invalid Argument`, no other information provide.

Comment: Which method of API you are using to complete the multipart upload. Also share the full error message and documentation you followed.

Comment: @SandeepVokkareni I have updated in the question. Thanks

Comment: Please let me know if the information below was helpful?

Comment: Sorry @SandeepVokkareni for the late reply. I have not got a chance to test it yet but I think the issue should be the minimum 5MB requirement. I will update here once I got the chance to check. Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The error `Invalid Argument` indicates that the problem occurred while sending the referenced request to Cloud Storage.

You need need to check on the below reasons which the cause the error:

1. With the XML api, POST methods are used to initiate the multipart upload and to complete it [1](https://cloud.google.com/storage/docs/xml-api/post-object), but to send the payload you have to use a PUT request. Once you have finished sending all parts, you send another POST request to finish the upload [2](https://cloud.google.com/storage/docs/xml-api/post-object-multipart).
2. Also make sure that you added the required header fields ["Date" and "Host"](https://cloud.google.com/storage/docs/xml-api/post-object-complete#:%7E:text=Date,Request%20Endpoints.) this is likely not what the error refers to but it will be required.
3. Also you need to check the file size of the full file you are attempting to upload as a multipart upload? One of the reasons this error can occur is because the part size used may be too small. If a non-ending part size is smaller than 5 MB this error is returned. The Minimum size of an individual part in a multipart upload is 5 MB as stated in the [Documentation](https://cloud.google.com/storage/quotas#requests:%7E:text=Minimum%20size%20of,5%20MiB).
4. There's a [public issue tracker](https://issuetracker.google.com/189001724) you may follow for updates on the improvement of this error message.

Also it seems like a common error which stated in the documentation you shared in the  [Common error codes](https://cloud.google.com/storage/docs/xml-api/post-object-complete#common_error_codes) section. There might be a possibility that parts specified in the request are not uploaded, ETag specified in the request not matching the ETag of the uploaded part or if the list of parts specified in the request are not in ascending order.

> If one of the parts specified in the request has not been uploaded, or if the ETag specified in the request does not match the ETag of the uploaded part, you get a 400 Bad Request status code and the body of the error response has InvalidPart in the Code element.
> If the list of parts specified in the request is not in ascending order, you get a 400 Bad Request status code and the body of the error response has InvalidPartOrder in the Code element.

If you still get the error, try to contact [google support](https://cloud.google.com/support-hub) as it requires project-inspection to find the cause of the error.

Comment: As commented in the question, the issue was due to the minimum 5MB requirement. Thanks!